# Form submission via AJAX / Detect validation erros

Tags: ajax, symfony, bootstrap-modal, fosuserbundle

I work with Symfony 3 + FOSUserBundle + Bootstrap modal

**The working part :**

I load the FOSUserBundle login form in a modal

I submit the form via AJAX

If the form has validation error, errors are displayed in the modal

**My problem :** 
When the form is valid, it shows my homepage inside the modal

**Question :** 
How to detect in the Ajax called if my form has erros or if form is valid ?
Because both return success for Ajax

Hope I'm clear... thanks for your help !!

**Here is the code**

Launch the modal :

```html
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModalLogin">Connexion</a>

<!-- Modale Login -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModalLogin" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
     <div class="modal-dialog"> 
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body" id="myModalLoginBody">
                {{ render(url('fos_user_security_login')) }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Modal content (extract only)

```html
...
<div class="container-fluid form-box">
 <div class="row text-center">
  <form action="{{ path("fos_user_security_check") }}" method="post" id="formLogin">
     <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token }}" />

     <div class="form-group">
         <input type="text" id="username" name="_username"  placeholder="Email ou Nom d'utilisateur" value="{{ last_username }}" />
     
         <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" placeholder="{{ 'security.login.password'|trans }}" />
     </div>
     
     <button type="submit" class="btn" id="_submit" name="_submit"> {{ 'security.login.submit'|trans }}</button>
  </form>
 </div>
</div>
...
```

AJAX

```js
$("#formLogin").submit(function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $form = $(e.target);
    $.ajax($form.attr('action'), {
        data: $form.serialize(),
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data) {
         // HERE IS THE ISSUE
         // My Modal is refresh to show validation errors => OK
         // But if no validation errors : user is logged inside the modal and homepage appear inside the modal
          $('#myModalLoginBody').html(data);
        },
        error: function() {
          $('#myModalLoginBody').html("Une erreur est survenue, veuillez réessayer plus tard");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, but not sure it's really clean...
So If you have better suggestion please do not hesitate !

**Solution :**

In my form I have a specific class for error messages :

```html
{% if error %}
   <span class="help-block">
   <ul class="list-unstyled">
   <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></span> 
     {{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}
   </li>
   </ul>
   </span>
{% endif %}
```

So in AJAX I test if this class is loaded :

```js
// PopIn login via AJAX
$("#formLogin").submit(function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $form = $(e.target);
    $.ajax($form.attr('action'), {
        data: $form.serialize(),
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data) {
          if(data.search('help-block') > 0 )
          {
            // Recharge la modal pour afficher les erreurs
            $('#myModalLoginBody').html(data);
          }else{
            window.location.reload();
          }
        },
        error: function() {
          $('#myModalLoginBody').html("Une erreur est survenue, veuillez réessayer plus tard");
        }
    });
});
```

So know I can reload the modal to show errors or reload the page to close the modal and connect the user !